# Use pycuda with reikna fft

Tags: python, fft, pycuda

Trying to find a quick way to compute fft on GPU. For other calculations, i use pycuda.
It would work pyfft for me, but it is already outdated, and i cannot install it via pip.
I use reikna, but using it, i cannot use the data that is in the GPU.
Because of this, I re-upload them.

```
fnc_coor(data_gpu, ta_gpu, fnci, Nri, Nai, s_rf_gpu, block=(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1),grid=grid)
 
api = any_api()
thr = api.Thread.create()
fft = FFT(s_rf, axes=(1,))
fftc = fft.compile(thr)
s_rf_gpu = thr.to_device(s_rf_gpu.get())
fftc(s_rf_gpu, s_rf_gpu)
```